# Cannot Install Squeak and Pharo Smalltalk on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I cannot manage to install Squeak and Pharo Smalltalk on Mac OS X 10.9.

as general a smalltalk system is composed of three elements; a VM, an image(if any changes to image then a changes file), and a sources file.

on squeak page
I have downloaded all in one linked file, but it does to include an .image or .sources. it includes a  .app. on the page this is mentioned to be the VM on mac, and it is mentioned to include all files one require. anyway double clicking does not launch smalltalk.

on pharo page
similar promise but does not launch again. it says download that file it includes everything necessary and just run the executable. but it includes .image .changes and .sources files in sub directory of /Pharo2.0.app/Contents/Resources.

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:
for squeak I have also found the .image .change and .sources files in some sub directory of the all-in-one. Should i, both for pharo and squeak, move these files to the same directory with the .app file.
UPDATE:
i have tried so. no change.

UPDATE:
because it is not signed upon first launch i modify settings to launch it authorizing as admin user one time. no problem with that.

Comment: The one-click images **do** include everything needed to run. The following links to the Pharo 2.0 one-click release: http://files.pharo.org/platform/Pharo2.0-mac.zip (just tested on 10.9, works fine). Can you try again please? Also, if it doesn't work, could you post your console log?

Comment: When you say does not launch smalltalk what exactly happens? Do you get a dialog box?

Comment: 08/01/14 22:37:17,210 com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[283]: ([0x0-0x58058].org.pharo.Pharo[648]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13

Comment: 08/01/14 22:37:17,214 Dock[317]: no information back from LS about running process LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x58058}

Comment: 08/01/14 22:37:19,945 CoreServicesUIAgent[650]: Unable to continue stopped application -- error -600

Comment: i hope these are the all required ones.

Comment: i have tried squeak installer on a windows machine on lab, it works but not on my mac, nor does pharo. from the impression i have taken from smalltalk there i am impatient for start using it on my laptop after that smalltalk here. come on community any solutions!?:)

Comment: Have you read this: [Running app on MacOSX Mountain Lion: Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13](http://superuser.com/questions/478768/running-app-on-macosx-mountain-lion-job-failed-to-exec3-for-weird-reason-13)

Comment: oh, i will repeat the process and reproduce the console log and look again.

Comment: ah you mean the artickle, i am trying chmod then.

Comment: Yes making the .app file i have downloaded make it work. now boy squeak and pharo smalltalks works. i've made `chmod +x pharo.app` and `chmod +x Squeak-4.4-All-in-One.app`

Comment: how to marked as answered my question. may be MartinW you can post below as an answer,for others look for same thing see clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem emerged from the fact that the application I had downloaded from Squeak or Pharo websites were not executable in my computer.

Issuing a change mod add executable command from terminal solves the problem for each one.

```
chmod +x /path/to/smalltalk/squeak/or/pharo/apps
```

Answer (score 3):

The first time you run the Squeak all-in-one, you need to right-click the app and choose "open". Then you will get a dialog that let's you run it. If you just double-click you get the same warning dialog, but without the option to run it.

This is because the Squeak app is not signed with an Apple developer key.

Comment: no i did this thing as it is common with unsigned dev apps. no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

You also can to change the run permission in System Preferences (Security Preferences), from "Map App Store" to "Anywhere".

Comment: it is so set in my preferences. so tahat is not a problem. are there any answer solution for my problem.